# django.db.utils.DataError: value too long for type character varying(2)

Tags: django, django-models

I've added the following to my User model:

```
    COUNTRIES = (
        ('AD', _('Andorra')),
        ('AE', _('United Arab Emirates')),
        ('AF', _('Afghanistan')),
        ('AG', _('Antigua & Barbuda')),
        ('AI', _('Anguilla')),
       . . .
        ('YU', _('Yugoslavia')),
        ('ZA', _('South Africa')),
        ('ZM', _('Zambia')),
        ('ZR', _('Zaire')),
        ('ZW', _('Zimbabwe')),
        ('ZZ', _('Unknown or unspecified country')),
    )

    class CountryField(models.CharField):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            kwargs.setdefault('max_length', 2)
            kwargs.setdefault('choices', COUNTRIES)

            super(CountryField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        def get_internal_type(self):
            return "CharField"

class User(AbstractUser):
   ...
    country = CountryField()
  ...
```

This is the migration created because of this change:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('users', '0006_auto_20180207_1902'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='user',
            name='country',
            field=pulsemanager.users.models.CountryField(choices=[('AD', 'Andorra'), ('AE', 'United Arab Emirates'), ('AF', 'Afghanistan'), ('AG', 'Antigua & Barbuda'), ('AI', 'Anguilla'), ('AL', 'Albania'), ('AM', 'Armenia'), ('AN', 'Netherlands Antilles'), ('AO', 'Angola'), ('AQ', 'Antarctica'), ('AR', 'Argentina'), ('AS', 'American Samoa'), ('AT', 'Austria'), ('AU', 'Australia'), ('AW', 'Aruba'), ('AZ', 'Azerbaijan'), ('BA', 'Bosnia and Herzegovina'), ('BB', 'Barbados'), ('BD', 'Bangladesh'), ('BE', 'Belgium'), ('BF', 'Burkina Faso'), ('BG', 'Bulgaria'), ('BH', 'Bahrain'), ('BI', 'Burundi'), ('BJ', 'Benin'), ('BM', 'Bermuda'), ('BN', 'Brunei Darussalam'), ('BO', 'Bolivia'), ('BR', 'Brazil'), ('BS', 'Bahama'), ('BT', 'Bhutan'), ('BV', 'Bouvet Island'), ('BW', 'Botswana'), ('BY', 'Belarus'), ('BZ', 'Belize'), ('CA', 'Canada'), ('CC', 'Cocos (Keeling) Islands'), ('CF', 'Central African Republic'), ('CG', 'Congo'), ('CH', 'Switzerland'), ('CI', 'Ivory Coast'), ('CK', 'Cook Iislands'), ('CL', 'Chile'), ('CM', 'Cameroon'), ('CN', 'China'), ('CO', 'Colombia'), ('CR', 'Costa Rica'), ('CU', 'Cuba'), ('CV', 'Cape Verde'), ('CX', 'Christmas Island'), ('CY', 'Cyprus'), ('CZ', 'Czech Republic'), ('DE', 'Germany'), ('DJ', 'Djibouti'), ('DK', 'Denmark'), ('DM', 'Dominica'), ('DO', 'Dominican Republic'), ('DZ', 'Algeria'), ('EC', 'Ecuador'), ('EE', 'Estonia'), ('EG', 'Egypt'), ('EH', 'Western Sahara'), ('ER', 'Eritrea'), ('ES', 'Spain'), ('ET', 'Ethiopia'), ('FI', 'Finland'), ('FJ', 'Fiji'), ('FK', 'Falkland Islands (Malvinas)'), ('FM', 'Micronesia'), ('FO', 'Faroe Islands'), ('FR', 'France'), ('FX', 'France, Metropolitan'), ('GA', 'Gabon'), ('GB', 'United Kingdom (Great Britain)'), ('GD', 'Grenada'), ('GE', 'Georgia'), ('GF', 'French Guiana'), ('GH', 'Ghana'), ('GI', 'Gibraltar'), ('GL', 'Greenland'), ('GM', 'Gambia'), ('GN', 'Guinea'), ('GP', 'Guadeloupe'), ('GQ', 'Equatorial Guinea'), ('GR', 'Greece'), ('GS', 'South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands'), ('GT', 'Guatemala'), ('GU', 'Guam'), ('GW', 'Guinea-Bissau'), ('GY', 'Guyana'), ('HK', 'Hong Kong'), ('HM', 'Heard & McDonald Islands'), ('HN', 'Honduras'), ('HR', 'Croatia'), ('HT', 'Haiti'), ('HU', 'Hungary'), ('ID', 'Indonesia'), ('IE', 'Ireland'), ('IL', 'Israel'), ('IN', 'India'), ('IO', 'British Indian Ocean Territory'), ('IQ', 'Iraq'), ('IR', 'Islamic Republic of Iran'), ('IS', 'Iceland'), ('IT', 'Italy'), ('JM', 'Jamaica'), ('JO', 'Jordan'), ('JP', 'Japan'), ('KE', 'Kenya'), ('KG', 'Kyrgyzstan'), ('KH', 'Cambodia'), ('KI', 'Kiribati'), ('KM', 'Comoros'), ('KN', 'St. Kitts and Nevis'), ('KP', "Korea, Democratic People's Republic of"), ('KR', 'Korea, Republic of'), ('KW', 'Kuwait'), ('KY', 'Cayman Islands'), ('KZ', 'Kazakhstan'), ('LA', "Lao People's Democratic Republic"), ('LB', 'Lebanon'), ('LC', 'Saint Lucia'), ('LI', 'Liechtenstein'), ('LK', 'Sri Lanka'), ('LR', 'Liberia'), ('LS', 'Lesotho'), ('LT', 'Lithuania'), ('LU', 'Luxembourg'), ('LV', 'Latvia'), ('LY', 'Libyan Arab Jamahiriya'), ('MA', 'Morocco'), ('MC', 'Monaco'), ('MD', 'Moldova, Republic of'), ('MG', 'Madagascar'), ('MH', 'Marshall Islands'), ('ML', 'Mali'), ('MN', 'Mongolia'), ('MM', 'Myanmar'), ('MO', 'Macau'), ('MP', 'Northern Mariana Islands'), ('MQ', 'Martinique'), ('MR', 'Mauritania'), ('MS', 'Monserrat'), ('MT', 'Malta'), ('MU', 'Mauritius'), ('MV', 'Maldives'), ('MW', 'Malawi'), ('MX', 'Mexico'), ('MY', 'Malaysia'), ('MZ', 'Mozambique'), ('NA', 'Namibia'), ('NC', 'New Caledonia'), ('NE', 'Niger'), ('NF', 'Norfolk Island'), ('NG', 'Nigeria'), ('NI', 'Nicaragua'), ('NL', 'Netherlands'), ('NO', 'Norway'), ('NP', 'Nepal'), ('NR', 'Nauru'), ('NU', 'Niue'), ('NZ', 'New Zealand'), ('OM', 'Oman'), ('PA', 'Panama'), ('PE', 'Peru'), ('PF', 'French Polynesia'), ('PG', 'Papua New Guinea'), ('PH', 'Philippines'), ('PK', 'Pakistan'), ('PL', 'Poland'), ('PM', 'St. Pierre & Miquelon'), ('PN', 'Pitcairn'), ('PR', 'Puerto Rico'), ('PT', 'Portugal'), ('PW', 'Palau'), ('PY', 'Paraguay'), ('QA', 'Qatar'), ('RE', 'Reunion'), ('RO', 'Romania'), ('RU', 'Russian Federation'), ('RW', 'Rwanda'), ('SA', 'Saudi Arabia'), ('SB', 'Solomon Islands'), ('SC', 'Seychelles'), ('SD', 'Sudan'), ('SE', 'Sweden'), ('SG', 'Singapore'), ('SH', 'St. Helena'), ('SI', 'Slovenia'), ('SJ', 'Svalbard & Jan Mayen Islands'), ('SK', 'Slovakia'), ('SL', 'Sierra Leone'), ('SM', 'San Marino'), ('SN', 'Senegal'), ('SO', 'Somalia'), ('SR', 'Suriname'), ('ST', 'Sao Tome & Principe'), ('SV', 'El Salvador'), ('SY', 'Syrian Arab Republic'), ('SZ', 'Swaziland'), ('TC', 'Turks & Caicos Islands'), ('TD', 'Chad'), ('TF', 'French Southern Territories'), ('TG', 'Togo'), ('TH', 'Thailand'), ('TJ', 'Tajikistan'), ('TK', 'Tokelau'), ('TM', 'Turkmenistan'), ('TN', 'Tunisia'), ('TO', 'Tonga'), ('TP', 'East Timor'), ('TR', 'Turkey'), ('TT', 'Trinidad & Tobago'), ('TV', 'Tuvalu'), ('TW', 'Taiwan, Province of China'), ('TZ', 'Tanzania, United Republic of'), ('UA', 'Ukraine'), ('UG', 'Uganda'), ('UM', 'United States Minor Outlying Islands'), ('US', 'United States of America'), ('UY', 'Uruguay'), ('UZ', 'Uzbekistan'), ('VA', 'Vatican City State (Holy See)'), ('VC', 'St. Vincent & the Grenadines'), ('VE', 'Venezuela'), ('VG', 'British Virgin Islands'), ('VI', 'United States Virgin Islands'), ('VN', 'Viet Nam'), ('VU', 'Vanuatu'), ('WF', 'Wallis & Futuna Islands'), ('WS', 'Samoa'), ('YE', 'Yemen'), ('YT', 'Mayotte'), ('YU', 'Yugoslavia'), ('ZA', 'South Africa'), ('ZM', 'Zambia'), ('ZR', 'Zaire'), ('ZW', 'Zimbabwe'), ('ZZ', 'Unknown or unspecified country')], default=django.utils.timezone.now, max_length=2),
            preserve_default=False,
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='user',
            name='last_name',
            field=models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=150, verbose_name='last name'),
        ),
    ]
```

Python3 manager migrate produces this error:

```
django.db.utils.DataError: value too long for type character varying(2)
```

I did try changing max_length=150 in the alter above max_length=2, but it didn't help. So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Look closely at your migration - the `default` for the field is being set to `default=django.utils.timezone.now` - which is going to be more than 2 characters. Presumably you are setting this default when you initialise the field in your model?

Comment: delete the last migrate file inside the app if no other migration files do not have any dependencies with it, put the `max_length=150` from your model and run `makemigrations` again, then `migrate`